# How to load a CSV with two columns in Ruby and save it in 2 arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv

I want to load a CSV-file with two columns (each with a name and a row of numbers) and save only the numbers of the two columns in two different arrays.
Then I want to make some calculations with the data in those two columns, using two arrays to save the numbers of each column.

This is what I still have:

```
require 'csv'
filename = 'file.csv'
csv_data = CSV.read(filename, :col_sep => ";")
csv_data.shift
csv_data.each_with_index { |column, index_c|
  average = 0
  column.each_with_index{ |element, index_e|
    csv_data[index_c][index_e] = element.to_i
  }
}
csv_data = csv_data.transpose
```

How can I split the columns of `csv_data` in two arrays ?

Comment: Can you include an example of what the CSV file looks like and what output you're looking for?

Comment: the csv looks like:

       data1   data2
       1       5
       2       6
       3       7
       4       8

i need each column in one single array. here arr1, including (1,2,3,4), and arr2 including (5,6,7,8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for you creating your two column arrays without wasting storage reading the whole file redundantly into csv_data.

```
require 'csv'
filename = 'file.csv'
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
CSV.foreach(filename, :col_sep => ";", :return_headers => false) do |row|
  arr1 << row[0].to_i
  arr2 << row[1].to_i
end
```

Comment: now I have the problem, that I want to calculate the yield by arr1.each_cons(2) { |c| arr3.push(Math.log(c[1]/c[0]))}. there is the error: divided by 0, but why? where is the mistake?

Comment: I would presume because one of the values is arr1 is 0 and c[1]/c[0] raises ZeroDivisionError.  `arr1.each_with_index{|v,i| puts "found zero at index #{i}" if v == 0 }`